# MUI MenuItem NextJS Link : Error while using those components

Tags: next.js, material-ui, menuitem, appbar

I got an issue trying to use **MUI MenuItem** and **NEXTJS13 Link**.
Versions:
MUi: "@mui/material": "^5.13.5",
NEXTJS: "next": "13.4.5",

import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import { Link } from "next/link";

https://mui.com/material-ui/react-app-bar/

I've tried:
A)

```
<Link href={`/main`}>
  <a>
    <MenuItem key={1}>lorem</MenuItem>
  </a>
</Link>
```

Error showed:
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'muiSkipListHighlight')

B)

```
<MenuItem key={1}>
 <Link href={`/main`}>
   lorem
 </Link>
</MenuItem>
```

Error showed:
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
Check the render method of `ResponsiveAppBar`. (ResponsiveAppBar is the component I'm creating)

C)

```
function ALink() {
    return <Link href="/">lorem</Link>;
}
```

.
.
.

```
<MenuItem key={1} component={ALink()>
</MenuItem>
```

Error showed:
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
Check the render method of `MuiButtonBaseRoot`.

D) Just not know what to try, I added a  insie Link:

```
<MenuItem key={1}>
 <Link href={`/main`}>
   <a>lorem</a>
 </Link>
</MenuItem>
```

Error showed:
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

If I quit the Link, it works correctly. But it's not what expected.

```
<MenuItem key={1}>
  {/* <Link href={`/main`}>asd</Link> */}
  lorem
</MenuItem>
```

Thanks,

EDIT: I've answer this with a workaround, but when I need to use a Link to scroll in the same page, I got this problem. (The answer isn't market as correct because of this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the box solution.
Instead of using link, I used a button and then onclick function for this issue. When the MenuItem has the param of pageScroll = true, then it will be calling the fucntion onBtnClickDirect (and the url passed as param too).

```
 function move(url, pageScroll = null) {
    if (pageScroll !== true) {
      router.push(url);
    } else {
      onBtnClickDirect(url);
    }
  }
```

The other used functions:

```
const onBtnClickDirect = (goToRef) => {
  const goto = goToRef;
  setTimeout(() => {
    scroll2El(goto);
  }, 100);
};
const scroll2El = (elID) => {
  window.scrollTo({
    top: document.getElementById(elID).offsetTop,
    behavior: "smooth",
  });
};
```

So, up to now you can get two options for the same issue.

I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround
If someone got the same issue, it'll help:

Use userouter and push the site in a onclick event.

```
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
```

```
 const router = useRouter();
  function move() {
    router.push("/main");
  }
```

```
<MenuItem key={1} onClick={(event) => move()}>
  Lorem
</MenuItem>
```